# Why Rails Controller Action Method Requires Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

It's a brand new project. Here's the exact commands I've run:

1. `rails new MyProject`
2. `bundle install`
3. `rails generate controller Image`

I've added this one route:

1. `root :to => "image#process"`

I've added this function to the `ImageController` (`image_controller.rb`)

```
def process
  render :nothing => true
end
```

And finally I've removed the default `index.html`. When I run the project, it has an error saying process expects 0 parameters, not 1. So I modify the method to tell me what parameter is trying to be sent to process.

```
def process(arg)
  p arg
  render :nothing => true
end
```

The string "process" is printed to the screen. I've done several Rails projects before and never encountered this. Did I miss a step somewhere? Is this something new in Rails 3.0.10? Or maybe caused by Ruby 1.9.2? I think I usually use 1.8.7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not name an action as [process](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L117), this is an internal method for rails controllers, name it something else.

There's a bunch of other names you can't use for controller actions like render, params, request. Unfortunately there isn't a list of these things.

Comment: Oh I didn't even think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, in case you aren't using it, you can view all internal methods and classes here: [ruby doc with nav on top right](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/)

Helps me when picking names.